# Changing single column name (and pointing to it by functions)

Tags: r

The code:

```
A <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 3)
colnames(A) <- paste('trial', 1:3)
```

Let I want to name the third column with something different from `trial 3`: how may I?

Ok, now:

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
pred <- predict(var.2c, n.ahead = 8, ci = 0.95)
```

If I want to see the first value of `pred`, according to what `predict` method returns here, I have to input

```
> pred$fcst$e[1]
[1] 962.6557
```

You can see that I had to specify time series name `e` to obtain the value I wanted. If the code above was inserted into a function, it would not be possible to call `pred$fcst$e[1]` without specifying time series name, thereby it would not be possible to pass another time series data frame to our custom function.

Example: let `X` be a time series data frame. Then

```
pred.var <- function(X) {
   var.2c <- VAR(X, p = 2, type = 'const')
   pred <- predict(var.2c, n.ahead = 8, ci = .95)
   # return(pred$fcst$...) # Here lies the issue, because function must know X column name
}
```

As you can see from example above, function `pred.var` must know the name of the `X` column whose it must return the prediction but it cannot unless it is read from `X`.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: I haven't understood your question quite well yet, but you can access to the same number as `pred$fcst$e[1]` by doing `pred[[1]][[1]][1]` as you can see it doesnt require variable names.

Comment: What does the main question have to do with renaming the third column? I don't understand.

Comment: Ehmm... sorry, you know in the writer's mind questions seem always easier than reality :) By the way, that was about the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an element of a list either by `$e` or `[["e"]]`, where in the second one, you can use any character variable.  So these two things give the same value.

```
pred$fcst$e[1]
pred$fcst[[ colnames(Canada)[1] ]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
colnames(A) <- c("trial1","trial2","something-different")

head(A)
     trial1 trial2 something-different
[1,]     NA     NA                  NA
[2,]     NA     NA                  NA
[3,]     NA     NA                  NA
[4,]     NA     NA                  NA
[5,]     NA     NA                  NA
[6,]     NA     NA                  NA
```

"something-different" is just any name of course.

Comment: erm... my answer is obviously only for the very first question. couldn't make the connect between the first and the rest.

Comment: Ok, what if I need to modify third column name without replacing the first two?

Comment: you can subset the colnames() function: `colnames(A)[3] <- "bla"`